# php session lost after redirecting with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a index.html login page with a JavaScript page called index.js attached to it. these two files are locally on my pc.
In the index.js I have an ajax call that authenticate the username and password with a page called index.php that sits on the web server.
In the index.php I start a session and check the authentication of the username and password and echo back the result. if successful, I redirect to an event.html page that is on the server.
The problem is that the session is not passed on although the index.php and the event.html are on the same web server. I see two different session cookies on the hindex.html and the events.html

index.js:

```
$.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:"http://example.com/index.php",
        beforeSend: function(xhr){
                xhr.withCredentials = true;
        },      
        data:$('#LoginForm').serialize(),
        success:function(response){  
            response = response.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
            alert(response);
            if(response == "client logged in")
               window.location.href = http://example.com/events.html';
        },
        error:function(xhr, status, error){
            var t = JSON.stringify(xhr);
            alert(t);
        }
});
```

index.php:

```
<?php
include 'head.php';
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");

error_reporting(0);
if(isset($_POST['username']) &&isset($_POST['password']))
{
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];
    if(!empty($username) && !empty($password))
    {
    $query="SELECT user_id
            FROM users
            WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password' ";
    $run_query=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
}
write_to_ses('user_id',$user_id);
echo "client logged in";
?>
```

head.php:

```
<?php
if(session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) 
{
  session_start();
}
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
error_reporting(0);

function write_to_ses($session, $data)
{
    $_SESSION[$session]=$data;
}
function read_from_ses($session)
{
   $user_id = $_SESSION[$session];
   return $user_id;
}
?>
```

**Edit:**
Could it be a cross domain issue? because i am moving from a local html to an html page on the server although all php files are on the server.

**Edit2:**
I am moving from a local html to a server html. So maybe the index.php stopping the session and the events.php starting a new session?

**Edit3:**
Just passed the events.html to my pc, so there is no moving from client to server html. still not working. same domain and same path two php files and two different sessions instead of one.

**Edit4:**
I removed all the headers. when running the index.html from my pc it gives me this error: "XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://example.com/index.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access."

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, you need to fix this. You are storing passwords in plaintext, you need to fix his also.

Comment: This is a work in progress not a final project

Comment: Doesn't matter, doing it properly drastically changes logic, so its not feasible to just do it the way you're doing it then fix it all in one go.

Comment: Where is the session not passing to?

Comment: the next page is events.html that gets ajax information from events.php all sitting on the web server. but the events.php has a different session id then the index.php

Comment: a page that is .html will not execute php. Page extension has to be .php for it to read the session variables. .html pages are static and they don't maintain state.

Comment: @RobertRocha It appears as though OP is making an ajax request from an HTML page to a PHP page to get the information stored in session. Which would work fine.

Comment: @JonatanKuhn - It should but it dosent

Comment: Can you explain why you are trying to set up CORS here, when from your description absolutely nothing seems to be cross-domain …?

Comment: @CBroe - Where do you see I am trying to setup CORS?

Comment: @t1a2l well what did you think all those `Access-Control` headers are for …?

Comment: @CBroe - this header ('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *') is needed by the ajax call. it gives me an error without it. the ("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true") header is used to allow Credentials on the ajax call and aloowed at the beginging to pass the session forword. it worked for 10 minutes and stopped working.

Comment: So your page that the request is made from is _not_ reached via `http://example.com/...`? Otherwise, not cross-domain ...

Comment: @CBroe - can you explain what you mean? i am doing an ajax call getting a response and move forword using windows herf location and one the next page doing anthor ajax call to a diffrent php page on the server but it dosen't recognize an open session and instead creating a new one.

Comment: You said you needed to set that Allow-Control stuff, so that AJAX was working. Which makes no sense, if you are not really making any cross-domain requests.

Comment: @CBroe - OK but can it make the session not to work? or create a new session on every page?

Answer (score 1):

$_SESSION will be set (albeit empty) even if you haven't started the session, so using !isset($_SESSION) will always return FALSE.

Change your code to:

```
if(session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) 
{
    session_start();
}
```

Comment: Just to continue, this is the same for all the superglobal arrays, `$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_SESSION`, `$_COOKIE`, `$_FILES`...etc. They are always set. Just an empty array if no data for that particular array was passed.